# Mysql substring query

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

I have a table of region restriction for product codes. Product code doesn't have a fixed length, bud it could vary between 10 to 25 numbers. The restriction could contain a prefix of a product so, that all product from in that range will be forbidden.
Used DB is MariaDB/Mysql and here is a table definition:

```
CREATE TABLE product_restrict (
    `id` VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL,
    `region` VARCHAR(3) NOT NULL,
    `from_dttm` DATETIME NOT NULL,
    `to_dttm` DATETIME NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`region`, `id`, `from_dttm`))
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

At this moment, I use 15 queries defined by the length of the target product code, so I'm able to find all of the prefixes, so in my code, I have 15 queries like that:

```
SELECT * 
FROM product_restrict
WHERE
 region='XXX' AND
(
    id = "9" OR 
    id = "98" OR 
    id = "987" OR 
    id = "9876" OR 
    id = "98765" OR 
    id = "987654" OR 
    id = "9876543" OR 
    id = "98765432" OR 
    id = "987654321" OR 
    id = "9876543210" OR 
    id = "98765432109" OR 
    id = "987654321098" OR 
    id = "9876543210987" OR 
    id = "98765432109876" OR 
    id = "987654321098765" OR 
    id = "9876543210987654" 
) AND (
 now() >= from_dttm AND
 ( now() < to_dttm OR to_dttm is null)
);


SELECT * 
FROM product_restrict
WHERE
 region='XXX' AND
(
    id = "9" OR 
    id = "98" OR 
    id = "987" OR 
    id = "9876" OR 
    id = "98765" OR 
    id = "987654" OR 
    id = "9876543" OR 
    id = "98765432" OR 
    id = "987654321" OR 
    id = "9876543210" OR 
    id = "98765432109" OR 
    id = "987654321098" OR 
    id = "9876543210987" OR 
    id = "98765432109876" OR 
    id = "987654321098765" OR 
    id = "9876543210987654" OR 
    id = "98765432109876543" 
) AND (
 now() >= from_dttm AND
 ( now() < to_dttm OR to_dttm is null)
);
```

In this table, is around 100 millions of records. My question is, is there a way to reduce this to a single query with the same select performance? Change of table structure is unfortunately out of my power.

---

*Edited after INSTR() hint from @Pham X. Bach:*

I did some tests on my local sample DB, where I have only 670 000 sample records, and the INSTR() is working, but from the performance perspective, it looks much worse. I'll have to wait till tomorrow, to do this test on the production sample.

Here is analyze (explain) for my original query:

```
Id  select_type table               type    posible_keys    key     key_len ref     rows    r_rows      filtered    r_filtered  Extra
1   SIMPLE      product_restrict    range   PRIMARY         PRIMARY 201             17      2.00        76.47       100.00      Using where
```

And here for the INSTR:

```
Id  select_type table               type    posible_keys    key     key_len ref     rows    r_rows      filtered    r_filtered  Extra
1   SIMPLE      product_restrict    ref     PRIMARY         PRIMARY 98      const   335022  671732.00   100.00      0.00        Using where
```

INSTR query, for example:

```
SELECT * 
FROM product_restrict
WHERE
 region='XXX' AND
 INSTR('98765432109876543', id) = 1 AND (
 now() >= from_dttm AND
 ( now() < to_dttm OR to_dttm is null)
);
```

Comment: Can you please provide some sample data with required output?

Comment: 1. Your `(...OR...)` condition could be replace by simple function `INSTR()` (and could combine with `LENGTH()` too). 2. You said you're using 15 queries but you only show 2 queries in your question.

Comment: Field ID is varchar despite the fact it is number. The length of this number is somewhere between 1 to 25 and it could be really any number with that length.
Field region is alfa numeric country code ("USA", "MEX", "DEU" and so on")
Field from_dttm is date and time of inserting this item to the table.
Field to_dttm is date and time, which means that this item is from that date invalid.

Comment: Yes, I show only two queries, for example, could you please show me the equivalent of that with `INSTR()` use?

Comment: `AND INSTR('98765432109876543', id) = 1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, there is no reason you can't just adjust your current query:

```
SELECT pr.* 
FROM product_restrict pr
WHERE pr.region = 'XXX' AND
      now() >= pr.from_dttm AND
      ( now() < pr.to_dttm OR pr.to_dttm is null) AND
      pr.id in ('9', '98', . . ., '98765432109876544',
                '9', '98', . . ., '98765432109876543'
               . . .
              )
```

There should be no problem having an `IN` list with a few hundred entries.  The duplicate entries are okay, but you can also remove them.

You can write this more simply using `like` or regular expressions.  For example:

```
WHERE pr.region = 'XXX' AND
      now() >= pr.from_dttm AND
      ( now() < pr.to_dttm OR pr.to_dttm is null) AND
      ('98765432109876544' LIKE concat(pr.id, '%') OR
       '98765432109876543' LIKE concat(pr.id, '%') OR
       . . .
      )
```

However, `IN` probably performs better.

Comment: Thank you, the `IN` version looks perfect.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a simple like condition

```
SELECT * 
FROM product_restrict
WHERE  region='XXX' 
AND '9876543210987654' like concat(id, '%')
AND (
      now() >= from_dttm 
      AND ( 
         now() < to_dttm OR to_dttm is null
      )
) ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way to check the prefix.

```
AND LEFT('9876543210987654', LENGTH(id)) = id
```

It is probably impossible to design a way that avoids a table scan, checking all ids.